# How to search for a paper when you have journal name, volume, issue, and year?

Tags: reference-managers

Is there an easy way to search for a paper in Science or Nature by the volume, issue number and year?

For example:

```
Science 317, 1500 (2007)
```

Comment: 1500 is not the issue number but the page number.

Comment: Just Google it.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know OP's definition of *easy way* but it only took me 2 minutes to go to the journal's webpage, click on the archive, go to year 2007, open up some of the issues in volume 317 and finally find page 1500 in issue 5844:

- http://science.sciencemag.org/content/317/5844

Year, volume and issue (and page numbers) exist to make finding an article *easy*. I'd say, that's *easy enough* but might be wrong. Yes, having a DOI is *easier*.

Page 1500 actually includes 4 technical comments:

- http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1138179
- http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1138764
- http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1138956
- http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1138773

Comment: Exactly. It's like finding a house if you 'only' have the house number, street, and zip code.

Comment: @henning Best. Analogy. Ever!

Comment: I love this analogy! Accordingly, the DOI would be the geo tag.

Answer (score 8):

#### Put it in to Google Scholar

In general, Google scholar is very good. You can copy a full reference into Google Scholar and it will often return just the article you are looking for. In general, this works well, for example, you can copy and paste the reference from a journal article into the Google Scholar search box and get the article.

Presumably, this process is less reliable when you don't have the title or author names, but sometimes, year, journal, issue, and page numbers may be sufficient.

For example, this is the search result when you plug it into Google Scholar
https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=Science+317%2C+1500+(2007)&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C39&as_sdtp=

[image]

### More generally

Most official academic search engines such as Scopus and Web of Science will have an advanced search that may facilitate narrowing your search to specific field codes.